# C printf %c character printing

Tags: c, memory, character

The following code prints (compiled with clang)

Output

```
[A][?][?]
```

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char a = "A";
    printf("[A]");
    printf("[%c]", a);
    printf("[%c]", "A");
}
```

Gives a warning (clang does)

```
test.c:4:10: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing
      'char' with an expression of type 'char [2]' [-Wint-conversion]
    char a = "A";
         ^   ~~~
test.c:7:20: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      'char *' [-Wformat]
    printf("[%c]", "A");
             ~~    ^~~
             %s
```

However

Output

```
[A][z][z]Characters: a A
```

Code

```
int main(){
    char a = "A";
    printf("[A]");
    printf("[%c]", a);
    printf("[%c]", "A");
    printf ("Characters: %c %c \n", 'a', 65);

}
```

I'm thinking it has something to do with the memory and integers (both because of the warning and because the "A" that is rendered as a "?" goes to a "z", that is "A"--).

Comment: turn on your compiler warnings, and read a beginners' tutorial about characters and strings in C.

Comment: The compiler's message perfectly explains what is the problem with your code.  I don't know how to explain it any better than this.

Comment: @5gon12eder I disagree is is completely in obvious (and stupid) to assume a differentiation between '' and "" when it comes to most languages that don't differentiate and I have never seen any mention of '' and "" being different from any tutorials or classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `"A"` is a `const char[2]` string of `'A'` and `'\0'`.  Use:

```
char a = 'A';
```

to get what you appear to be after.

Comment: So using "" and '' produce different results?

Comment: @Zimm3r `'A'` and `"A"` are different.  Curious: Do you expect `'A'` and `"A"` to be the same thing?

Comment: @Zimm3r very much so, `""` is used to create C compile-time strings of type `const char [<string-length>]` where as the C language uses `''` to ceate compile-time `char` constants.

Comment: @chux yes I have never seen it be different in Python, Javascript, or C++.

Comment: @Zimm3r C++ uses these same rules -- it inherited then from from C

Comment: Guess you learn new things. I have never ran into this, from C classes to tutorials etc.

Comment: @Zimm3r But C is neither JavaScript nor Python. It's pointless to assume that one language's syntax/semantics follows that of another one.